# Oracle PL/SQL and Java dependencies

Tags: java, sql, oracle, tomcat, plsql

When a `PL/SQL` package is invalid, Java code accessing this package reports an exception that the `PL/SQL` is invalidated. However, when the `PL/SQL` block is recompiled and it is in **valid** state, Java still reports the same error. When the web server is restarted, the error vanishes.

Is it possible to resolve this issue without restarting the server?

Comment: How come your package is invalid? Is this in production? if so check why package is in invalid state.

Answer (score 1):

Going to go out on a limb here and suggest that you reset your connection pool. The package state may be tied to the opened connection, and closing and reopening it can fix that.

As to how to do that, that will depend on your container. Some containers support doing that from using an administrative function.

I don't think that connection validation will catch this problem, but that might work as well.